# Google analytics count dimension clicked

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have code to showing ads. I want to track **views** and **clicks** for widget_id (dimension).
If page loaded, the widget will showing some ads, and GA will add count for widget_id viewers, and if user click the ads, GA will be add count for widget_id click.
Results from analytics must be :

```
widget_id (dimension1) | unique pageviews | click (?)
-----------------------|------------------|----------
   1                   |       100        |    14
   2                   |       200        |    50
```

The question is: How to setup adding/sending data for clicks using dimensions, events, or metrics?

Thanks.

Comment: I cant fully understand what you need but if you want to count something you should be using custom metrics not dimensions.